# Raspberry Pi: Autostart Program in Full Screen

Tags: pi-3, gui

I put the program `leaflet` on Autostart by adding

```
@leafpad to ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pie/autostart
```

Now it starts after the GUI load is finished. But it is not starting in full screen or with maximized size.

I didn't find a solution about this. Does anybody have a tip?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use leafpad and you can get away with using chromium browser, then you can run that in kiosk mode like this:

```
@chromium-browser --kiosk --incognito http://localhost:3000
```

I don't know leafpad enough to know if it supports kiosk mode.

Comment: Address in this case would be your leaflet daemon.

Comment: Thanks Bungee75 for your answer. I didn't get it work, that leafpad isn't loading in maximized Windows Modus. But with your Tipp working with the Chromium Browser, what is possible to start in Fullscreen, i mad a solution on HTML Base instead of leafpad.

Comment: Does F11 make it full screen? If so the package Xautomation could help, using xte 'key F11' -x:0

Answer (score 0):

try xdotool which you can control your mouse without human interference and try to maximize your window using the below commands for example:-

1. xdotool click1
2. xdotool mousemove 1700 20
3. click 1 is the left button of the mouse and click2 is the right button of the mouse & 1700 and 20 are the coordinates of the point you want to press and